# Calling a function from within nested functions in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope, each

I'm guessing this is a scope problem, but I can't work it out! I have a function which validates a form before sending. On submit, it iterates through each field and checks the details. It should then set a cookie for each value, since the form sends the user away from the site, temporarily, and I need that data when they return.

I have a set cookie function that works just fine, but calling this function from within two nested functions just does nothing.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("form#mainRequestBrochure").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();     //prevent form.submit()
        var missingData = 0;        // missing required fields counter
        $("form#contactForm input").each(function(index) {
            var ok = 0;
            var v = $(this).val();
            var n = $(this).attr('name');   
            if(isBlank(v)===true) {         // if empty
                $(this).addClass("error");  // add error class
                missingData++;              // add one to  counter
            } else if(($(this).attr('type')==="email")&&(!isValidEmailAddress(v))) {
                $(this).addClass("error");  
                missingData++;
            } else if ($(this).hasClass("error")) {     // not empty but has had error class applied
                $(this).removeClass("error");           // clear error class
                ok = 1;
            } else {
                ok = 1; 
            }
            if(ok===1) createCookie(n,v,7);
        });
        createCookie('Testing2','test',7);
        // if no errors recorded, submit the form
        if(missingData === 0 ) $("form#mainRequestBrochure").submit();
    }); 

});

function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
    alert('cookie ' + name + ' set.');
}
```

The code directly inside of `$("form#mainRequestBrochure").submit(function(event)` works fine, creating the cookie named Testing2 using `createCookie('Testing2','test',7)`, but when I place that same line of code within the `.each()` loop, it does nothing.

Like I say, I'm guessing this is a scope thing, but it's driving me up the wall....

Comment: Should "form#contactForm input" be changed to "form#mainRequestBrochure input"?

Comment: the bug lies in your createCookie method.  show us that code

Comment: Added, please see above. It appears okay to me...

Comment: whererhys -- oh good god, I can't believe I made a mistake like that. you are absolutely right. Cut'n'paste is the worst thing ever, after sloppy coders.

Answer (score 0):

Move the createCookie function outside of the submit function.